# React testing by input type

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-testing-library

I am trying to test my below component in which I am returning dynamic control based upon the switch condition:

```
const DataTableFormControl: FC<DataTableFormControlProp> = ({ displayName, isRequired, dataType, content, cellId }) => {

  return (
    (() => {
      switch (dataType) {
        case DataType.NUMBER:
          return <TextField
            id={cellId}
            label={displayName}
            defaultValue={content}
            required={isRequired}
            type="number"
          />
        case DataType.DATE:
          return <TextField
            id={cellId}
            label={displayName}
            defaultValue={content}
            type="date"
            required={isRequired}
          />
        case DataType.BOOLEAN:
          return <FormControl variant="standard">
            <Typography>{displayName}</Typography>
            <Switch color="primary" defaultChecked={content === 'true'} />
          </FormControl>
        case DataType.PERCENT:
          return <FormControl variant="standard">
            <Typography>{displayName}</Typography>
            <Input
              id={cellId}
              defaultValue={content}
              required={isRequired}
              endAdornment={<InputAdornment position="end">%</InputAdornment>}
            />
          </FormControl>
        default:
          return <TextField
            id={cellId}
            label={displayName}
            type="text"
            required={isRequired}
            defaultValue={content}
          />
      }
    })()
  )
};

export { DataTableFormControl };
```

I tried below way to find the item but, how I can run an assertion based upon the `TextField` type and check if we are getting  or have `endAdornment` property?

```
   describe('DataTableFormControl', () => {
      test('should render component with text dataType', () => {
        const { container } = renderControl(DataType.TEXT);
        const textElement = container.querySelector(`#${cellId}`);
        expect(textElement).toBeInTheDocument();
        // How we can run find if this element is type of text, date, or number.
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In general React testing library discourages testing props just for the sake of checking that props passed to a component. The whole idea of React testing library is writing tests that translate to "how this is effecting the user?". In other words, a better test would check how does the existence of a prop affect the DOM (and by extension, the user), instead of just checking if a prop was passed or not.

I would also recommend avoiding using `querySelector` and to use `getBy...` queries which should be able to find any item you are looking for. In your case, since you are looking for inputs `getByRole` would be best. Depending on the type of the input you can do `getByRole('textbox')`, `getByRole('checkbox')` and so on.